# What does "pares" mean in this sentence from the "Living Latin" reader?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

I am having trouble understanding this sentence from Living Latin: A Graded Reader:

> Pro isto vestro in me officio pares agere gratias vix possum, referre nequaquam!

I guess it means something like

> I can hardly thank you enough for this favor you have done for me, let alone repay it!

But I can't parse the grammar of the first part of the sentence, "in me officio" is "for me", but "pares" and "vestro" sound out of place to me. I am surprised there is no relative clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the general idea, but *in me officio* doesn't go together to mean 'for me.'

*Pares* modifies the accusative *gratias*, and the phrase means 'equal thanks.'

*Vestro*, like *isto*, modifies the ablative *officio*, which is the object of the preposition *pro*. Therefore the phrase means 'for that service/favor of yours.'

The prepositional phrase *in me* (where *me* is accusative) limits *officio*, 'duty toward me.'

Therefore, the first part of the sentence means, 'I am scarcely able to give equal thanks for that service/favor of yours toward me.' A relative clause *could* have been used to express 'that service/favor that you did for me,' but the prepositional phrase (*in me*) gets the idea across just as well and without cluttering the sentence.